# < operator for a class with no members

Tags: c++, sorting, operator-overloading

Is there a convention for this? It mostly just needs to work with sorting in stl containers.

I have considered a few possibilities, like comparing the address of the two objects, or just always returning true but I am not sure what is best. Would always returning true mess with sorting algorithms?

```
class empty {
    bool operator< (const empty& rhs) const {
        // ???
    }
}
```

P.S. 
 It can happen in odd cases like when a class only gets member variables based on a #define etc, or when the class is already written by someone else and you don't want to radically change it but you need to put it or a class that transposes it into certain containers that require a less-than operator.

Comment: "Would always returning true mess with sorting algos?" Yes. Apart from that I am convinced that we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please explain more about what you want to achieve, less about how you think you could do it.

Comment: If you want it to be sortable, then what sorting order do you expect? That should lead you to the decision of what to return for sorting.

Comment: sorting is about defining a criterion (or comparison). When you designed your class, which criterion did you considere to be relevant for sort?

Comment: thinking a bit more, I guess the criteria I think makes most sense for an empty object is to express that all instances are equal, so I guess per @John Zwinck answer it should always return false. I'll wait a bit before accepting in case better answers appear.

Comment: Why do you want to sort this kind of objects in the first place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the type "sortable" but don't actually care about the sort order, you can make the less-than operator always return false.  Making it always return true would cause some algorithms to fail, because if `A<B` and `B<A` then it is not a "strict weak ordering."  Making the operator always return false expresses the idea that all instances are equivalent.  If you use a stable sort algorithm, no elements will move.

If you need an actual ordering of some kind but don't really care what it is (e.g. for putting elements into a `std::map`), you can `return this < &rhs` to compare by address.  Note that this is not suitable for `std::sort()` because when the algorithm swaps values their addresses will not change, but it is OK for `std::map` and `std::set` because those do not rely on moving values around.  See the comments below from Peter for caveats.

Finally, notice that a class with no members still consumes one byte of storage.  You could store a `uint8_t` or `char` in the class at no increase in space, and use that as the sort criterion.

Comment: The result of comparison `this < &rhs`  is unspecified unless both objects are elements of the same array, or are non-static members (or sub-objects) of the same object

Comment: @Peter: I said "If you need an actual ordering of some kind but don't really care what it is" - so the fact that the ordering is unspecified is fine.  It is not undefined behavior, and it will work in practice on any sane machine.

Comment: Before C++17, `this < &rhs` gives undefined behaviour (unless both objects were elements of the same array ....). The result of `this < &rhs` is now unspecified in C++17 (unless both .....)  but it *is* specified that neither pointer will compare greater than the other. That will break standard algorithms (like `std::sort()`) because the comparison will not implement a strict-weak ordering, and standard algorithms have undefined behaviour if the comparator does not define a strict-weak ordering.

Comment: @Peter: It will only cause UB if pointer-less returns true for both `A<B` and `B<A`, or if it is non-deterministic (`A<B` is sometimes true and sometimes false for fixed A and B).  Do you know of any system where either of those is true?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of a case where `A<B` changes over time for fixed (address) `A` and `B`.   But that's missing the point.   Let's say we have two elements of an container `X` and `Y`.   If `X < Y` is true, then a sorting algorithm may swap them.   Under a strict weak ordering,`Y < X`  will now be true.    However, if the comparison compares their addresses, it is not.

Comment: @Peter: That's a fair point, different to the one I thought you were making.  In my answer I mention comparing addresses for the purpose of putting them in a `std::map`, which I think is still valid.  I'll edit the answer to mention that it isn't suitable for `std::sort`.  Thank you.

Comment: `std::map` requires a strict weak ordering of the keys as well.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, but std::map (or std::set) does not swap elements around by value, instead it just mutates the pointers to adjacent nodes.  Since there's no swapping, your concern about what happens if two values are swapped does not apply.

Comment: Point is that the behaviour of `std::map` is undefined if keys don't have a strong weak ordering.